# Strip html tags from text before adding it to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, strip-tags

When user fills a form on my site, it's sent to server with jQuery ajax, and server returns the results similar to this:

```
<p>Sivustosi päivittyy usein tai silloin tällöin, joten julkaisujärjestelmä on sivustolle välttämätön. 
Sivusto rakennetaan <a href="http://fi.wordpress.org/" target="_blank">WordPress-julkaisujärjestelmään.</a> 
WordPress on erittäin helppokäyttöinen alunperin blogeja varten kehitetty julkaisujärjestelmä, joka monipuolisuutensa takia soveltuu myös isojenkin yritysten julkaisujärjestelmäksi.</p>

<p>Se että sivu erottuu massasta kaikin tavoin, 
vaatii paljon tutkimusta muista alan sivuista, ja vaatii aikaa. </p>

Valintojesi perusteella hinta voisi olla 330€ + ALV 23%(75.9€)
```

Then user has an option to close the window that has the results, or to contact me with the results added to the message, so I need to strip the html tags as gmail shows them, and they're shown on the textarea too. How would I do this as my ajax call which adds the text to textarea is like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "calculate.php",
        data: calculation_data,
        error: function (failure) {
            $('#result').html("Palvelimelta ei saatu tietoja. Internet-yhteytesi on mahdollisesti poikki, tai serveri on ylikuormittunut. Yritä hetken päästä uudelleen. ");
            $('#hintalaskuri .control-group').slideUp();
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
            $('#hintalaskuri .control-group').slideUp();
            $('#hintalaskuri .modal-footer').prepend('<a href="#tarjouspyyntö" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">Lähetä tarjouspyyntö</a>');
            //add text to textarea
            $('#tarjouspyyntö [name=hintalaskuri]').val(response);

        }


    });
```

adding $(html).text(); to the success function didn't help, so how would I do this?

Comment: "adding $(html).text(); to the success function didn't help" You mean: $('#tarjouspyyntö [name=hintalaskuri]').val($(response).text());  doesnt work?

Comment: No, I mean adding `$(html).text();` **before** $('#tarjouspyyntö [name=hintalaskuri]').val(response);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already added the html to one of your elements.. so grab the text from that element

```
$('#tarjouspyyntö [name=hintalaskuri]').val($('#result').text());
```

Comment: This removes the whitespace also, is there a way to keep the whitespace?

Comment: @roasted what would happen to the text that isn't wrapped in any tags though?  I don't think you can create a jquery object from a string

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen You mean the linebreaks?

Comment: No, it removes **all** spaces from text.

Comment: oh, i guess it leaves spaces then.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('#result').text()` to get only the text of the result without HTML tags (after adding it to the DOM with `$('#result').html(response);`)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tarjouspyyntö [name=hintalaskuri]').val($(response).text());
```

And if you want spaces between the elements:

```
var resultHtml = "";
$(response).each(function(index,value){
       resultHtml += $(value).text() + " ";
});
$('#tarjouspyyntö [name=hintalaskuri]').val(resultHtml);
```

Comment: it produced undefined to the start of the text.